# Linking to a C library compiled as C++

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, linker, static-libraries

I'm in linker paradise now. I have a C library which only compiles in Visual C++ (it probably works in gcc) if:

1. I compile it as C++ code
2. Define `__cplusplus` which results in all the declarations being enclosed in `extern "C" { }`

So, by doing this I have a static library called, say, `bsbs.lib`

Now, I have a C++ project called `Tester` which would like to call function `barbar` in declared in `bsbs.h`. All goes fine, until I try to link to `bsbs.lib` where I get the all-too-familiar:

```
Tester.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _foofoo
```

And it always seems to be `foofoo` which cannot be resolved regardless of which function I call in `Tester` (`barbar` or anything else).

**Update:** I've expanded on Point 2 as requested. Thanks a lot for the help guys!

```
#ifndef _BSBS_H
#define _BSBS_H

/* Prevent C++ programs from name mangling these definitions. */
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

#include <stdio.h>
#include <setjmp.h>
.......
.......
#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif

#endif /* _BSBS_H */
```

This is the "main" header file, so to speak. All the important functions are here. But there are other header files called by the `bsbs.c` file which are **not** enclosed in `extern "C" {}`.

**Solved:**
OK, this is quite weird, but I removed the `extern C` bit from the header file in `bsbs`, compiled it as a C++ project (even though all the files are `.c` and removed the `__cplusplus` define) and it worked! I got the idea after looking at the symbol list. Everything was mangled **except** the ones enclosed in `extern C` (doh) and it was asking for an unmangled symbol so I figured something was amiss.

Comment: And you're not referencing "_foofoo" anywhere in the Tester code?

Comment: What exactly do you mean in point 2 - I think we need to see some code as that could be wrong

Comment: Is `foofoo` in a third library you are missing, i.e. `bsbs.lib` needs something else, by any chance?

Comment: The childhood innocence and naivety displayed in "compiles in VC (it probably works in gcc)" literally made me LOL

Comment: Why don't you compile the C library as C code? And you should not be defining `__cplusplus`  anywhere - it's up to the implementation to do that.

Comment: @mjmarsh: No. I tried calling a function which *does not call* `_foofoo` and yet `_foofoo` was the symbol the linker complained about

Comment: @Nikolai: No, `foofoo` is fully defined in the code. I even dumped the symbols from `bsbs.lib` and it was there.

Comment: @Terry: :) --- I think this code was written for `gcc` since I was able to compile and link `bsbs` without any modifications with Cygwin --- but I did not run it, so you may be right :D

Comment: @Neil: I tried that and I was bombarded with a deluge of syntax errors. I saw `__cplusplus` and the `extern` and thought of compiling it as C++ with `__cplusplus` defined and it worked --- maybe this was wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you declare them as extern C in the lib (which is unnecessary, if you're calling them from C++), then they must be extern C in your headers.

Comment: If they're extern C, they're extern C. You can't mix and match. If the lib exports them as extern C, then you MUST import them as extern C.

Answer (score 2):

There may be a dependency in the c library you're not including in your link. Does the c library you're including really a reference to a DLL? If so there's a program called 'depends' which will tell you what the other required DLL's are.

Comment: I don't think so since `foofoo` is defined in `bsbs.lib` and it seems to be independent.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you've added a linker reference. E.g.:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "bsbs.lib")
```

Comment: Well, I defined the input libraries elsewhere so it's reading `bsbs.lib`

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps the compiler/linker combination needs to be made aware of which APIs are to be exported/imported? If so I'd try adding the appropriate [`__declspec`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dabb5z75%28VS.80%29.aspx) (e.g., `dllimport` and/or `dllexport`) to the C++ library.

Answer (score 0):

Does your lib file import any other lib files?  You can compile a lib file to either explicity link lib files or implicitly.  One way you get the lib files in a huge ball, the other you get them as separate libs that all need linked at compile time in the final app.  If foofoo is imported in your lib file from another lib file, then include that lib file in your final project.  This is my best guess from what you described, and is by far the most common thing I get asked when dealing with lib files thru co-workers..

Comment: I don't think that's the case since `foofoo` seems to be completely defined.